# Response.Write in particular section of Markup

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, response.write

I have a web application in ASP.NET, C# and MS SQL Server. I am using an external CSS **Metro UI CSS** that provides me styled components like Tiles (similar to Win8), notices, buttons and so on. I want to show content fetched from the Database or calculated data in those styles **DIVs**. But since they are not ASP.NET controls, they cannot be bound to data sources.

I tried using `Response.Write("MY HTML CODE")` to generate content dynamically and that works but its not perfect as the content is placed different from the markup. I actually don't know what is the difference but it does not fit well into my existing static page content. Is there a way to insert content into existing HTML using `Response.Write()`?

Right now I am trying this,

```
Response.Write("<div class='message-dialog bg-color-blue fg-color-white' style='width: 50%; z-index:1000;'><h1>Congratulations!<br/></h1><h3>You Account is created.Please Sign In.</h3><a href='Default.aspx'><button class='button-set active bg-color-red fg-color-white' style='float:right'> OK </button></a></div>");
```

And this shows a Styles Box with proper text but that appears on the top of my existing page with `_z-index_` and behind page without it.

Comment: What does prevent you to convert the pure html controls to server side controls?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, may be the runat attrib!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any control, even a *specially styled div* can be modified in the server-side by adding the `runat="server"` attribute to it.

So in your aspx, you can do something like this:

```
<div class='message-dialog bg-color-blue fg-color-white' style='width: 50%; z-index:1000;' runat="server" id="myDiv" />
```

And in code behind do whatever you want... For instance:

```
myDiv.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Hello World" });
```

or even

```
 myDiv.InnerHtml = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
```

Using `Response.Write` is probably the wrong way to go in this situation...

Comment: Thank you, that was a very good explanation.
But I have a little more queries. Can I use <%eval()%> with these kind of controls? How can I position the elements inside the myDiv? Or alter their CSS properties?

Comment: Adding elements inside the div is done as I showed, using `Controls.Add` and changing the Css can be done using the `CssStyle` property